# Printing data variable

Tags: vuejs2

I am trying to print `data()` variable. I am not getting output in HTML template.

```
<template>
    <h3>{{app_skills}}</h3>   <!-- I am not getting value here -->
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "leftbar",
        data() {
            return {
                app_skills: '',
            }
        },
        methods : {
            fetchskills (url) {
                url = '/skills';

                axios.get(url)
                    .then(response => {
                        this.app_skills = response.data.skills;
                        console.log(this.app_skills) // I am getting value here
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        console.log(error);
                    });
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            this.fetchskills();
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: What's the data type of `app_skills`? If you `console.log(this)` when you get your response, is that spitting out your Vue component as expected?

Comment: Thanks @JohnEllmore for your reply. `app_skills` is a string. I couldn't understand your second question. Thanks.

Comment: Add the line `console.log(this);` right after your existing `console.log(this.app_skills)` statement. What does it print?

Comment: Thanks @JohnEllmore. I am getting this  https://i.stack.imgur.com/t0E0X.png . Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code worked exactly as expected when I tried it (with a few environment-related changes):

```
<template>
    <h3>{{app_skills}}</h3>   <!-- I am not getting value here -->
</template>

<script>
    import axios from 'axios';
    export default {
        name: "leftbar",
        data() {
            return {
                app_skills: '',
            }
        },
        methods : {
            fetchskills (url) {
                url = 'https://dns.google.com/resolve?name=example.com';

                axios.get(url)
                    .then(response => {
                        this.app_skills = response.data;
                        console.log(this.app_skills) // I am getting value here
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        console.log(error);
                    });
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            this.fetchskills();
        }
    }
</script>
```

All I changed was including the axios library, changing the URL to pull from, and changing the `response.data` key to pull. It all works as expected. Perhaps you have an issue somewhere else in your surrounding code?

Comment: Thanks @John Elllmore. I used same code in another repository and that is working fine. I tried for several hours to find out the issue but failed. Thanks.